# How to associate EmailMessage with Lead record using apex?

Tags: apex, leads, emailmessage

I am creating a new EmailMessage record from my apex code and I want that this record should be associated to a Lead record. As per documentation, we can not use RelatedToId

> RelatedToId :
> The RelatedToId represents nonhuman objects such as accounts, opportunities, campaigns, cases, or custom objects. RelatedToIds are polymorphic. Polymorphic means a RelatedToId is equivalent to the ID of a related object.

and if I try to use it , I get a

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION : Invalid id type

**Is there any way we can associate EmailMessage to Lead?**

The larger picture about what I have to do here is that:

We are sending an single email message from a lightning component button click through apex SingleMessage. When we do this, a record of activity history should be created for this lead and I have to add some custom fields on this activity history record to show some more information. I used `setWhatId` and `setSaveAsActivity(true)` methods of `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` class but that gives a similar error as `RelatedToId`:

> SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, SaveAsActivity is not allowed with whatId that is not supported as a task whatId.: [whatId, 00Q3a00000pHXf4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setWhatId, which sets the What Id (thing) for the activity, use setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId), which sets the Who Id.
Then you can set save activity, etc.

Comment: This will create an activity history record related to Lead alright. But I want to update some custom fields on this activity history record created for Lead. How can I achieve that? I can create a separate question for that if needed.

Comment: As this question is closed, added a new questions with more details:
 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343454/how-to-update-emailmessageactivity-histiory-associated-with-a-lead